# No tests found matching Method addtest

Tags: java, junit

I am learning Junit Testing, and I decided to make a simple calculator and test it.  I created *Calculation_JUnit* and Calculation_JUnit_Test

Also i have a problem of using class methods[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N3fw.png)

```
 package com.example;
public class Calculation_JUnit {
public static int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
public static int sub(int a, int b){
    return a-b;
}
public static int mul(int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}
public static int div(int a, int b){
    return a/b;
}
```

}

Calculation_JUnit_Test

```
  import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import com.example.Calculation_JUnit;


public class Calculation_JUnitTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("Test is passedd ");
    }
    @Test
    public void Add_Test ()
    {
        Calculation_JUnit calculation_jUnit = new Calculation_JUnit();
        Assert.assertEquals("Good",5, calculation_jUnit.add(2,1));
    }

    @Test
    public void Sub_Test ()
    {
        Calculation_JUnit calculation_jUnit = new Calculation_JUnit();
        Assert.assertEquals("Not Good",5, calculation_jUnit.add(5,1));
    }

    @Test
    public void Mult_Test ()
    {
        Calculation_JUnit calculation_jUnit = new Calculation_JUnit();
        Assert.assertEquals("Not Good",3, calculation_jUnit.add(5,1));
    }

    @Test
    public void Div_Test ()
    {
        Calculation_JUnit calculation_jUnit = new Calculation_JUnit();
        Assert.assertEquals("Not Good",5, calculation_jUnit.add(4,1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Not (all) directly related: while you *can* access static functions through an instance, I *wouldn't*, because it's counter to how most people see and think about Java. I'd recommend using standard Java naming conventions for your test methods, e.g., `addTest`, `subTest`, etc. Underscores in package names are *allowed*, but unusual. Underscores in variable names is unconventional at best.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please don't add screen shots of text, copy and paste the text into code block so it's easier to follow the question.